# Using Java Annotations - Generating Code

Tags: java, annotations

I'm using java 6 annotation processing api. I have followed the following excellent tutorial for creating an annotation processor that displays a message at build-time:

http://kerebus.com/2011/02/using-java-6-processors-in-eclipse/

However, in my case, I have a simple class as such:

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(value = ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Criteria {
    String id();
    double width();
    double height();
}
```

As you can see, the aforementioned annotation is made available to the JVM at runtime using the meta-annotation 'Retention'. I use this 'Criteria' annotation in the source code of another class to annotate a method, like so:

```
@Criteria(id = "fooBar", 
    width = 22, 
    height = 10
)
public void fooStream() {       
    System.out.println("foo stream method");
}
```

At runtime, I want to include the 'fooStream' method in another class, ONLY if variables that are passed in match the values of the elements in the @Criteria annotation, namely 'width' and 'height'. My question is, how could I take the method 'fooStream' and inject this into another class at run-time? Is this even possible? I'm not looking for any code examples, just answers to the two aforementioned questions. Also, in the link at the top, there is an example of generating a code using 'JavaFileObject' and 'Writer' instances, where the generated code is passed as a string.

Comment: What you're asking, inject a method into another class at runtime, does not compute in the java programming language.  There are no functions in Java.  You're more trying to create your own new programming language on JVM.

Comment: Can you please explain what problem are you trying to solve? How would you use an alien method in a class that has no idea about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want runtime modification of you **classes**, you can use your own classloader and intercept loading of classes, introspect what you want and generate new bytecode using asm library instead of original classes. It is not very tricky, but you must be sure you need exactly that.

Comment: I think this is the approach I need alright. I have read up some information on getting the annotations included in a class from this tutorial. I believe this is what I may need - http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/language/annotations.html

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe Java supports runtime type mutation, meaning to modify the members on a given class you'd have to drop back to a compile time preprocessor or to a bytecode modification scheme.

I'd be able to point you in a better direction if I understood the "why" behind this question, but in the mean time, [dynamic proxy classes](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/reflection/proxy.html) might get you to where you want to be ([JavaWorld article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-11-2000/jw-1110-proxy.html)).

From the documentation:

> A dynamic proxy class is a class that
>   implements a list of interfaces
>   specified at runtime such that a
>   method invocation through one of the
>   interfaces on an instance of the class
>   will be encoded and dispatched to
>   another object through a uniform
>   interface. Thus, a dynamic proxy class
>   can be used to create a type-safe
>   proxy object for a list of interfaces
>   without requiring pre-generation of
>   the proxy class, such as with
>   compile-time tools. **Method invocations
>   on an instance of a dynamic proxy
>   class are dispatched to a single
>   method in the instance's invocation
>   handler, and they are encoded with a
>   java.lang.reflect.Method object
>   identifying the method that was
>   invoked and an array of type Object
>   containing the arguments.**

Here's a decent [tutorial](http://artofsoftwarereuse.com/2011/01/19/using-spring-java-annotations-to-inject-reusable-capabilities/) on using Spring to inject dynamic proxies based on custom annotations.  I think this is probably closest to the behavior you're after.

Comment: The 'why' behind the question is that I will include the aforementioned code in a jax-ws web service. I only want to fire the method however if the criteria defined in the annotation is met. I don't want to go using lots of 'if/else' statements, so the annotations were a way for me to specify when a method should be included in the webservice at runtime. Is this making sense?

Comment: Yes.  Dynamic Proxies are still the way to go.  Writing a bytecode modification scheme is not simpler, and it's tremendous overkill if you're just trying to avoid some convoluted conditionals.

Comment: Originally said: "want to *include* the method in other class", taken to mean *define*; now clarify that wants to '*fire* the method', implying *invoke* the method.
Maybe: @fooBar(22,10) would generate code for: ???.fooStream(); Not clear where the annotation would be placed in the invoking usage...