# Java vs JavaScript getters and setters methods

Tags: java, javascript, callback, closures

Sometimes when i have some object with lots of attributes (for example 30-40) it is really anoying to write getter and setter methods so in javascript i do something like this:

```
function SomeObject( properties ) 
{ 
   // Iterate through the properties of the object, and make sure 
   // that it's properly scoped.
   for ( var i in properties ) 
   { 
       (function(){ 
        // Create a new getter for the property 
        this[ "get" + i ] = function() 
        { 
           return properties[i]; 
        };
        // Create a new setter for the property 
        this[ "set" + i ] = function(val) 
        { 
           properties[i] = val; 
        }; 
    })(); }
 }
```

So i am just wondering if it is possible to do something like this in JAVA?

Comment: *"it is really anoying to write getter and setter methods"*  Answer: IDE.

Comment: via reflection, yes. But why don't use code generation in your IDE?

Comment: i know i can use IDE. I use NetBeans and it offers such functionality. But the main question is if it is possible to be done programatically

Comment: Well, @jlordo pretty much summed it up in their first sentence.  But 'reflection' is usually the 'right answer to the wrong question'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose if i give you a class with 30-40 getters/setters. How would you feel while using. 
I don't think its a good idea to have 30-40 getter/setters in a single class. **Rather you break/distribute class by subclassing properties**

The example you gave from javascript is avery good example. On how we should access if we so many properties in a single class. In javascript you can tread a object like a Map.

I would apply the same idea if i have the requirement of 30/40 getter setters.

i.e Either i would use java.util.Properties

or made My Custom Class

```
  //Only if you have 30/40 properties
  class MyClass {

       private Map<String, Object> data = new ConcurrentHashMap<String,Object>();

       public void set(String fieldName, Object value) {
               data.put(fieldName, value);
       }

       public Object get(String fieldName) {
               return data.get(fieldName);
       }

   }
```

Answer (score 3):

Code-generating annotations can do this sort of thing in Java.  You might want to take a look at [Project Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/).

Related, I think: [Using Java Annotations - Generating Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229411/using-java-annotations-generating-code)

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse:

Rightclick -> Source -> Generate Getters and Setters

There are also other nice generators, for example, for constructors, hashCode/Equals.

All common IDEs have such a functionality, which saves *alot* of time.

Comment: i know that. But how to do it programatically based on the the arguments in the constructor?

Comment: Javascript is a script language. Java should be compiled. 
It make no sense to create methods dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse you can use the function "Source > Getter and Setter" and automatically will be added in your code all the setter and getter that you want!

Comment: there should be such option in NetBeans too .

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try ascepects and Spring Roo like :

```
@RooJavaBean
public calss SimpleClass {
    private Attr1 attr1;
    private Attr2 attr2;

}
```

[Tutor](http://www.cubrid.org/blog/textyle/377946)